# Override nova route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using nova 4 and laravel 9

I want to override the default nova controller
so when I click button save
will post/put to customController

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Post\StoreController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Post\UpdateController;

Route::post('/{any}/{resource}/new', [StoreController::class, 'handle'])
    ->where([
        'any' => 'nova-api',
        'resource' => 'posts'
    ])->name('nova.api.')->middleware('nova');

Route::put('/{any}/{resource}/{resourceId}', [UpdateController::class, 'handle'])
    ->where([
        'any' => 'nova-api',
        'resource' => 'posts'
    ])->name('nova.api.')->middleware('nova');
```

I've tried like this but still not working

[image]

when I click save, the route still not overriding
for sure I just add `dd('tes')` on my controller for  check if this route work or not